Questions on the proof of the existence of an $\omega$-saturated elementary extension
Both David Marker in his Model Thoery: An Introduction and Anand Pillay in his notes use "compactness" to prove that there exists an elementary extension of any model $\mathcal{M}$ realizing all types over finite subsets of $\mathcal{M}$ without detailed argument.
While Bruno Poizat in his A Course in Model Theory, proves this proposition as Theorem 5.1., by the fact that every type is realized in an elementary extension and that elementarily equivalent structures have a common elementary extension. And the latter is only mentioned by Marker as Exercise 2.5.11
So my question is: Does this proof only need compactness in a way, or did Marker and Pillay simply omit these details?

"every type is realized in an elementary extension" That statement is a corollary of compactness. There's only one proof here: repeatedly applying compactness (or its corollary if you prefer), keep adding types until you've achieved saturation.

There certainly needs to be some argument for moving from realizing a single type to realizing a whole set of types, but I think it can still be fairly called "by compactness", but also fairly called "omitting the details".
But the idea is simple. Poizat uses an amalgamation argument (that maybe ironically makes more direct use of compactness than the argument I imagine Marker and Pillay have in mind), but you can also just go purely "vertically"... enumerate the relevant type space $p_\alpha$, then make an elementary chain $M_\alpha$ where $M_0=M$ and $M_{\alpha+1}$ is an elementary extension of $M_\alpha$ realizing $p_\alpha$ and taking unions at limit stages and at the end.

Actually, thinking about it, there's a simple argument just using compactness once "all at once". Let $p_i$ be types (assume WLOG that they are complete) and consider the theory $\operatorname{Th}_M(M)\cup\bigcup_i p_i(\vec c_i)$ where $\vec c_i$ are all new constant symbols. Then any finite subtheory is equivalent to something extending to something of the form $\operatorname{Th}_M(M)\cup\{\phi_{i_1}(\vec c_{i_1}),\ldots, \phi_{i_n}(\vec c_{i_n})\}$ where $\phi_{i_k}\in p_{i_k},$ and since the $p_i$ are types, these formulas are all realized in $M,$ so the subtheory is consistent.

Actually this is my very first thought but I refused to continue with it unconsciously. Even though Marker has already demonstrated the enumeration of uncountable cardinals in the previous text, I'm still not used to it. And I believe Poizat uses amalgamation just to bypass it. Is it kind of "transfinite" argument?

@YSouSerious Yes this is a transfinite recursion argument (and note if we're being careful there are some more basic things to verify, like that types stay consistent when we pass to an elementary extension). Based on other remarks in the text, I agree bypassing transfinite recursion could be the motivation for Poizat's more horizontal approach, but it may also just be more natural to him. But transfinite recursion is used pretty frequently, particularly in contexts where we're trying to find a structure of a certain size with a certain level of saturation, so I'd recommend getting used to it.

@YSouSerious I'm pretty used to just bashing through things with transfinite recursion so my perception that this is the "standard" way to do this part may be biased (though Noah's comment seems consistent with it). For instance, if someone had initially told me the variation on Poizat's argument I just added to the answer, I would probably view that as "the way to do it".

@YSouSerious If you want to keep reading model theory, you should try to get used to transfinite recursion arguments. They are an indispensable tool in the subject. Note that even after the "all at once" construction in spaceisdarkgreen's edit, we now have an elementary extension $M'$ of $M$ realizing all types over finite subsets of $M$. But $M'$ is not yet $\aleph_0$-saturated, because there are new types over finite subsets of $M'$ which are not realized. So we have to repeat this construction - again by recursion. Here "ordinary" recursion (on $\omega$) suffices.

...but if you want to achieve higher levels of saturation, you need to iterate the "realize all types" construction transfinitely.
